# Problem with Trendnet wifi

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have wifi adapter TEW-646UBH. It works perfectly with ubuntu 14.04, but after upgrade to 16.04 Adapter freezes sometimes, especially after active downloading

This is output of `lsusb`:

```
rnovikov@romanovi-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 20f4:646b TRENDnet 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 0a5c:2190 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Comment: If iy is a USB adapter add output of `lsusb` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 the info you asked for is here.

Comment: I have no solution for this device.